# How to make Services available in Azure VPS

Tags: windows, azure, vps

I have some VPS's on the windows azure cloud.

I add all my web services, ftp services, make sure to allow them in the firewall and free up all ports, but i am still unable to hit the vps with the DNS nor the IP they give me...

How can i do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Did you open up the endpoints in Management Portal? By default, Azure puts up a security perimeter around your VM that is in addition to the VM's firewall rules. You need to explicitly open up endpoints if you want to connect to other ports from outside their data centers.

In the Azure Management Portal, go to the Virtual Machines tab and select your VM. You should see a tab for "ENDPOINTS". Add your ports there and see if it works now.